# If bacterial plasmid DNA is methylated then how do we digest it using restriction enzyme in cloning experiments?

Tags: molecular-biology, cloning

So, I was reading about how bacteria protects its own DNA by methylation against restriction enzyme. But if the plasmid DNA is also methylated then we can't cut plasmid using restriction enzyme for doing cloning. And if we are isolating this plasmid from Methylase deficient strain so that the plasmid is not methylated, won't it would be digested by the bacterial restriction enzyme. Do we isolate these plasmid from a strain that is also unable to produce restriction enzyme ?